# Issues getting all entries inserted into a MySQLi database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using a form to retrieve information from Amazon, and then insert that information into a MySQLi table.  My problem is that some records are inserting perfectly while others will not insert at all.  Here is the query to insert into the table ( yes, I know it is wide open for sql injection, but I need to get it working correctly before I make it web safe):

```
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO video (upc, title, manufacturer, rating, platform, weight, listed_price, release_date, asin, image)
    VALUES ('$upc', '" . addslashes($amazonResult['Title']) . "', '" . addslashes($amazonResult['Author']) . "', '" . $amazonResult['Rating'] . "',
         '" . $amazonResult['Platfrom'] . "', " . $amazonResult['Weight'] . "," . $amazonResult['ListPrice'] . ",
         '" . $amazonResult['PublishDate'] . "', '$asin','" . addslashes($amazonResult['ImageURL']) . "' )");
```

As far as I can tell there are no errors being generated.
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some of those sanitized variables probably have unescaped quotes which is causing the integrity of the query to fail. It's ghetto, but put `addslashes` on all the `amazonResult` variables and see if it works. If not, check all your queries and see where the syntax is wrong.

Comment: _"need to get it working correctly before I make it web safe"_ ... You may get it working _by_ making it "web safe". Why `addslashes()` and not `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, or better yet a prepared statement?

Comment: `echo` your query first. And what mysql error do you get?

Comment: @phpisuber01 - I added the addslashes as suggested and there is no difference. - when I echo the query I have the information where it should be, but it will not insert it into the table on some records but will in others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes, I know it is wide open for sql injection, but I need to get it working correctly before I make it web safe

You're doing it upside-down.
Injection is but a result of *improperly formatted code*.
So your insert problem most likely of the same source.

Thus, if you properly format your code, you will hit both goals at once.

> As far as I can tell there are no errors being generated.

You have to ask mysqli for them.
Run all your queries at least this way

```
$sql = "..."
$conn->query($sql) or trigger_error($conn->error."[$sql]");
```

to be notified of the error and the problem query.

Comment: Taking your suggestion, I was able to track down the error, which was that these two fields " . $amazonResult['Weight'] . "," . $amazonResult['ListPrice'] . ", need to have ' in front of them.  Seems to work perfectly now.